# Use parameter value as in select in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, select, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a parameter named `event` whose value is say `event_val` in an XSLT file used for transforming an XML.

I want to get `<xsl:value-of select="event_val"/>` but the resultant transform is `event_val` within `<TimeCommenced>` block.

The code is as follows:

```
<xsl:param name="event"/><xsl:template match="/">
<Event>
      <TimeCommenced>
        <xsl:variable name="time_commenced" select="$event"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$time_commenced"/>
      </TimeCommenced>
</Event>
```

Comment: Unclear.  I think you may be saying you want to pass in an element name (e.g. 'event_val') as a parameter, and use it to initialize the variable `time_commenced`.  But you're not currently getting the value of the root `event_val` element; instead you're getting the name you passed in as a parameter.

Comment: I want `event_val` to be the value of `time_commenced`. Does that help?

Comment: Not much.  If you want the string "event_val" to be the value of the variable `time_commenced`, your existing stylesheet should work, if passed the string 'event_val' as the value of parameter `event`.  If you want something else, you should say what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contents of a parameter is a *string*, not an *XPath expression*. If you have a parameter named "param" and it contains the string "last_name", then the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="param"/>
```

will be evaluated as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="'last_name'"/>
```

resulting in the literal string "last_name" being output.

Passing the parameter to a variable makes no difference and is entirely redundant. Try instead something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = $param]"/>
```

if you want to get the contents of a node named "last_name". Or (preferably, IMHO) find some other (less awkward) way to handle the issue.